# Birkat HaGomel and Tehillim

Tags: travel, hagomel

I once met a Chabadnik who said Tehillim (I forget which) at the end of a journey instead of Birkat HaGomel. Is this normal among:

1. Chabadnikim?
2. (Any) other Chasidim?
3. Other groups of Jews?

Does anyone say Tehillim instead of Birkat HaGomel and, if so, what do they say?

Comment: most people do not say Birkat HaGomel after (normal) journeys these days, since routine travel is not dangerous or risky anymore.

Comment: Cf. [*B'rachos* 9:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%98_%D7%93) ("הנכנס לכרך מתפלל שתים אחת בכניסתו ואחת ביציאתו בן עזאי אומר ארבע שתים בכניסתו ושתים ביציאתו ונותן הודאה לשעבר וצועק לעתיד לבא").